# transform with No Output

Tags: c++, loops, vector, transform, stl-algorithm

I have two `vector`s of the same size. I need to modify each element of one `vector` by the contents of the other `vector`. Is there a standard algorithm that accomplishes this without assigning back to the original `vector`?

So say I want to modify all the elements of `vector foo` by the corresponding element of `vector bar`. I can use `transform`:

```
transform(foo.begin(), foo.end(), bar.begin(), foo.begin(), [](auto& a, const auto& b){a.func(b); return a;});
```

But that assignment back to `foo` is unnecessary. Alternatively I can write my own function:

```
auto a = foo.begin();
auto b = bar.begin();

while(a != foo.end()){
    (a++)->func(*(b++));
}
```

But I'd rather not reinvent the wheel if there's something already there.

Comment: Do you not want to store the result of the operation, or do you want to store it in a different vector?

Comment: @blasko I do not want to store the result. I want a `transform` function which does not have an output iterator and disregards the lambda return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest answer to this seems to be using an index rather than an iterator.

```
for(auto i = 0; i < foo.size(); ++i) foo[i].func(bar[i]);
```

It's only requirement is analogous to that of any multiple input iterator algorithm: All containers must have at least the same range as indicated by the first pair of iterators. Here meaning that all containers should be of size greater than or equal to `foo.size()`. Unlike the abuse of `transform` this can be extended to support as many bracket-operator-accessible containers as desired:

```
for(auto i = 0; i < foo.size(); ++i) foo[i].func(bar[i], baz[i], buz[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is basically a [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) for binary functions.
Since there is no such thing (yet), you could do one of the following:

**1) Implement a generic version of such a `for_each` for binary functions:**

(code taken from https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-proposals/fNqx2TR-ju8/MIqPwgSoWukJ)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2, class BinaryFunction>
BinaryFunction for_each(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1, InputIt2 first2, BinaryFunction f)
{
    for (; first1 != last1; ++first1, ++first2) {
        f(*first1, *first2);
    }
    return f;
}

struct Foo
{
    Foo() : k(-1){}
    int k;
    void func(int i){k=i;}
};

int main() {

    std::vector<Foo> foo(5);
    std::vector<int> bar(5,55);

    for_each(foo.begin(), foo.end(), bar.begin(), [](auto& a, const auto& b){a.func(b); return a;});

    for(auto f : foo)
    {
        std::cout << f.k << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**<kbd>[live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7492229b5ac36b99)</kbd>**

**2) Use `boost::zip_iterator` and the existing `std::for_each`:**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp>

struct Foo
{
    Foo() : k(-1){}
    int k;
    void func(int i){k=i;}
};

template<typename... Iterators>
auto zip(Iterators... its)
{
    return boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(its...));
}

int main() {

    std::vector<Foo> foo(5);
    std::vector<int> bar(5,55);

    auto zip_func = [](auto&& t){t.template get<0>().func(t.template get<1>());};
    std::for_each(
        zip(foo.begin(), bar.begin()),
        zip(foo.end(), bar.end()),
        zip_func
    );

    for(auto f : foo)
    {
        std::cout << f.k << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**<kbd>[live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54ad0584b78f525b)</kbd>**

Comment: You say "no such thing (yet)" should I hold out hope that there is something forthcoming?

Comment: @JonathanMee the linked std proposal is from 2013, I don't think this will appear anytime soon

Comment: I've finally take the time to read through that whole thread. It looks like it never went further than someone commenting on a forum that this would be nice to have. As mentioned in the thread, `boost::zip_iterator` doesn't look like it has a place in the standard in the near future either. As I thought about it for `vector`s there seems to be very little motivation for putting anything in place in the standard: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31775609/2642059

Answer (score 2):

Small utility function template:

```
template <typename Input1, typename Input2, typename BinaryOperation>
void zip(Input1 b1, Input1 e1, Input2 b2, BinaryOperation binOp) {
    while (b1 != e1) binOp(*b1++, *b2++);
}
```

Usage:

```
zip(begin(foo), end(foo), begin(bar), [](auto& a, const auto& b){ a.func(b); });
```